# xcode bug, crash adding refactored storyboard onto a new group

Tags: ios, xcode

I have refactored Storyboard because I want to have each viewController in the folder with it's view files.

After choosing the viewController in storyboard -> editor-> refactor to storyboard and to create the new storyboard file, it appears on top of the project, even on top of the xcode.proj file.

[image]

When I try to drag the storyboard file to another folder, instead of to move, it copies a new instance inside a folder, but the main one remains on top. 
I've tried to create a new folder clicking on the storyboard file, and selecting add to new group, but this causes xcode to crash. 
Any one knows a solution to this bug? I would like to move this file to it's folder and remove it from the top of the project.
I'm working with xcode 9.2 (9C40b)

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Nope, did it happened the same to you ?